# How to synchronise the version in the Setup project with the version of the main application?

Tags: visual-studio, versioning, setup-project

I have a desktop application project where I manage the version number using the `Automatic Versions` tool. The app can read and display the version number at runtime.

Now I want to create a `Setup` project to help distribute the app. The Setup project has its' own version number as well as `ProductCode` and `UpgradeCode`.

Is there a way to automatically synchronise the App version and the Setup version or is it something that must be done manually?